# Protocol-relative scripts and styles for Wordpress site behind Cloudfront

Tags: wordpress, amazon-cloudfront

Ok, so here's the scenario. I have a WordPress site hosted on Fargate, sitting behind an ALB, sitting behind Cloudfront. I have an ACM cert mounted on the distribution to enable client-server TLS, but have  Cloudfront communicating with the origin over http (so I don't need to provision certs for each site and add to the ALB, which has a hard cap at 25 certs).

Now, here's where things get tricky. Since Cloudfront is communicating over HTTP, I need to set the Site URL of the WordPress site to HTTP. However, the issue is this results in all scripts and styles enqueued with `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` - respectively - being loaded over HTTP, which throws up a bunch of mixed content warnings. I could hack something together in the `wp_enqueue_x` methods to serve all assets protocol relative, but it feels like there should be a better way.

Comment: *"so I don't need to provision certs for each site and add to the ALB, which has a hard cap at 25 certs"* ... any or all of which can also be multi-domain and/or wildcard certs.  I'm not sure you're solving the right problem by avoiding TLS between CloudFront and the balancer.

Comment: The issue with that is that you can't go back and modify existing certs e.g. to add additional names. And in all likelihood this service will be supporting more than 25 unique domains.

Comment: That's true, but once you've validated a domain using DNS for use with Amazon Certificate Manager, you can get a new cert with that name plus another, etc., because the validation hash for a given domain doesn't change... then swap them out on the balancer.  But I use a single `*.origin.example.com` cert for sites behind CloudFront, point that wildcard at my ALB in DNS, and then assign a new `foo-site.origin.example.com` domain name for use as the Origin Domain Name for each site in CloudFront -- no balancer changes needed.

Comment: hm, point well-taken re: _get a new cert with that name plus another_, however I'm not following the idea behind the wildcard subdomain cert. Say I provision a new Wordpress site in multisite and it has the subdomain `foo-site.origin.example.com`, where multisite has the address `origin.example.com`. Then, I provision the cert for `*.origin.example.com` and mount that cert on the ALB + CloudFront (which is what you're suggesting, yes?). Then, I want the domain `foo.com` to point to `foo-site.origin.example.com`. I'm not understanding how in the above configuration this would work.